# latex Template for Elsevier journal

Tags: templates, journal-publishing

Where can I find the LaTeX template for Elsevier Camera-ready copy (CRC) journals (Neuroimage journal) for publishing my paper?

Comment: https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The journal [Neuroimage](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/neuroimage/1053-8119/) isn't using CRCs as far as I could see. The page Sam Carter posted includes a section on CRC typesetting for LaTeX articles.

Comment: @ Sweitse, I used Latex to write my paper, for this why I am asking for a CRC template.

Comment: CRC templates are only used for journals using camera-ready copy. For Neuroimage you can use the regular LaTeX template.